# init.d script getting error

Tags: linux, debian, init.d, mmonit

First of all sorry for my bad english

Ok, i wrote a init.d script and i don't know its true or false (i am new at this things)

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/init.d/someserver

start () {
    echo -n $"Starting someserver.jar: "

    java -jar /home/someserver/someserver.jar &
    echo $! > /home/someserver/someserver.pid
}

stop () {
    echo -n $"Stopping someserver.jar: "

    PID=$(/home/someserver/someserver.pid) 
    kill -9 $PID
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}

case $1 in
    start)
        start
    ;;
    stop)
        stop
    ;;
    *)

    echo $"Usage: someserver {start|stop}"
    exit 1
esac
```

after that i use this commands;

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/someserver

$ sudo update-rc.d someserver defaults
```

i am getting this info;

```
insserv: warning: script 'someserver' missing LSB tags and overrides

/etc/init.d/someserver: 6: .: 3: Too many open files
```

I search the errors and info's but i can't understand so what does it mean and what should i do?

Note:os debian, and i writing this for mmonit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at other init scripts for reference?

Let's go through this section by section. First let's name a shell to be executed. Ok.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Now please put LSB tags there as the init system suggests (tells the init system the dependencies)

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          someserver
# Required-Start:    $syslog $network $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $syslog $remote_fs
# Should-Start:      $local_fs $named
# Should-Stop:       $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: someserver
# Description:       Some Server
### END INIT INFO
```

Then you sourced the init script itself, why? That's probably why the error you mentioned occurs, as this way it's called recursively, which is probably not what was intended.

Usually you source some script to get a config or so:

```
# source some config (can be omitted)
[ -f /etc/configs/someserver ] && source /etc/configs/someserver
```

Why do you have the dollar signs in every `echo` statement? (Ok, localization, I believe)

(Note: By looking at some other init script you see that debian uses the start-stop-daemon to manage daemons, so you may implement that. I don't do that here.)

```
start () {
    echo -n "Starting someserver.jar: "

    java -jar /home/someserver/someserver.jar &
    echo $! > /home/someserver/someserver.pid
}
```

You forgot a `cat` in `stop()`.

Also I would not necessarily `kill -9` but first only `kill`. You can put in a check if it really disappears and then `kill -9`. Again, maybe you should use `start-stop-daemon`.

```
stop () {
    echo -n "Stopping someserver.jar: "

    PID=$(cat /home/someserver/someserver.pid) 
    kill $PID
}
```

You generally want to wait a little bit before restarting

```
restart() {
    stop
    sleep 10
    start
}
```

Finally you should also implement `restart`.

```
case "$1" in
    start)
      start
      ;;

    stop)
      stop
      ;;

    restart)
      restart
      ;;

    *)
      echo "Usage: someserver {start|stop|restart}"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac
```

Wasn't that bad. But you missed some details.

Comment: Thank you i did it and it works now and i do some changes `screen -A -m -d -S someserver java -jar /home/someserver/someserver.jar
    screen -list | grep someserver | cut -f1 -d'.' | sed 's/\W//g'  > /home/someserver/someserver.pid` little bit complex but it works